# <meta charset="UTF-8"> not validating

Tags: html, utf-8, w3c-validation

I am working on a final project for class, but I keep getting an error when I try and validate my site. The errors I am getting are:

[image]

1. > Error: The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using `windows-1252`.
2. > Error: A `charset` attribute on a `meta` element found after the first 1024 bytes.
   >
   > At line 15, column 24
   >
   > ```
   > charset="utf-8">↩      <meta nam
   > ```
3. > Error: Changing character encoding `utf-8` and reparsing.
   >
   > From line 15, column 4; to line 15, column 25
   >
   > ```
   > -->↩   <meta charset="utf-8">↩     <m
   > ```
4. > Fatal Error: Changing encoding at this point would need non-streamable behavior.
   >
   > At line 15, column 25
   >
   > ```
   > charset="utf-8">↩      <meta name][1]
   > ```

I'm not sure why I keep getting this, as I haven't had trouble getting things to validate before. I tried moving the `<meta charset="utf-8">` to be the first child element in the header, but that ended up causing more errors.

Here is the top portion: (the supporting file page is one line. Is that line to big maybe?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML LANG="EN">
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>NO. 83 COMICS</TITLE>
<!--

  No 83 Comics Website (IS 139 674 Web Publishing Final Project)
  Author: Nate Contini
  Date: 12/06/2018

  Filename: No83Home.html
  Supporting files: Assets/Javascripts/modernizr.custom.62074.js, 
  fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Scrhtmlipt, 
  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat, Paladin 
  Style.css,Assets/Images/no_83_logo_D6T_icon.ico, 
  connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2, 
  https://www.facebook.com/groups/508106072637180/, 
  https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw, 
  https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js, https://www.tumblr.com/share, 
  https://assets.tumblr.com/share-button.js, no 83 home.html, No 83 Gallery 
  Page.html, creator page.html, newsletter Page.html, 
  https://www.amazon.com/, Assets/images/No 83 Logo 2.png, Paladin Bio 
  Page.html, Anne Sullivan Bio Page.html, Mr. Freedom Bio Page.html, Dale 
  Sulivan Bio Page.html,ID Bio Page.html, Obsidian Blaze Bio Page.html,Flash 
  Strike Bio Page.html,Nuclear Ruin Bio Page.html

  -->
  <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
  <META NAME="VIEWPORT" CONTENT="WIDTH=DEVICE-WIDTH">
  <SCRIPT SRC="ASSETS/SCRIPTS/MODERNIZR.CUSTOM.62074.JS"></SCRIPT>
  <LINK HREF="HTTPS://FONTS.GOOGLEAPIS.COM/CSS?FAMILY=MARCK+SCRHTMLIPT" REL="STYLESHEET">
  <LINK HREF="HTTPS://FONTS.GOOGLEAPIS.COM/CSS?FAMILY=MONTSERRAT" REL="STYLESHEET">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is your meta tag within the <head> section of your page? More info & code would help here

Comment: It is in the head section. Here is the top portion

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML LANG="EN">

   <HEAD>
   <TITLE>NO. 83 COMICS</TITLE>

   <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
   <META NAME="VIEWPORT" CONTENT="WIDTH=DEVICE-WIDTH">
   <SCRIPT SRC="ASSETS/SCRIPTS/MODERNIZR.CUSTOM.62074.JS"></SCRIPT>
   <LINK HREF="HTTPS://FONTS.GOOGLEAPIS.COM/CSS?FAMILY=MARCK+SCRHTMLIPT" REL="STYLESHEET">
   <LINK HREF="HTTPS://FONTS.GOOGLEAPIS.COM/CSS?FAMILY=MONTSERRAT" REL="STYLESHEET">

Comment: You have to include a minimal example (in the question, not in a comment → [edit]) that gives the errors. The markup you posted doesn’t seem to be responsible for the errors, it validates (line 15 seems to be the problem, but your markup probably has less lines -- or did you add many line breaks?)

Comment: The error messages appear to say that there’s a `<meta charset="...">` declaration in the middle of the document. Did you perhaps write it more than once?

Comment: It’s generally a best practice to put the `charset` declaration as close to the top of the document as possible, since it literally says to start parsing the document all over again according to that character set. So maybe put it, once and only once, right after `<head>`.

Comment: What does line 15 actually look like? You have only shown the first 9 lines.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Lines 5-14 are comment lines. Ibut I can update the top to reflect that.

Comment: @Davislor I did have a second one in there some how (probably a copy paste error) but when I removed it, I am still getting the same message on the validator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: A charset attribute on a meta element found after the first 1024 bytes.

… and you have a massive comment immediately before it which uses up about 1025 bytes by itself.

Move the `<meta>` element to before that comment.

Comment: I just tried that, but that caused more errors. If the comment is the problem, then I am not sure how to work around it. Sadly it is required in my class to have the comment like that.

Comment: Then fix the new errors. Assuming they *are* new errors and not just errors that you didn't see before because the validator gave up after hitting the *Fatal Error* in your screen shot (in which case you should still fix them).

Comment: Cool! Thanks! That removed that error, now I have just a ton others lol.